# Extract double quotes using boost::regex in C++Builder

Tags: c++, regex, boost, c++builder

I am working on a lexer analyzer using **C++Builder XE6** and this is what I've done so far: I have two memos (**memoIN**, **memoOUT**). **memoIN** contains the text to be analyzed and **memoOUT** the output (list of **tokens**).
First, I strip the **memoIN** content from all comments using **boost::regex**, and this works like a charm. Now I'm stuck on how to extract all double quotes from the text and display them as a string in the output memo.

All iIhave so far is an expression that **removes** all double quotes but not what i need, i need to extract theme and display theme for example:

**memoIN :**

```
This is a "Double" Quote and this is "another one"
```

**memoOUT :**

```
<(String "Double") #Line 01 #Length 06)>
<(String "another one") #Line 01 #Length 11)>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using Boost.Regex**

Here's some sample code that demonstrates using `boost::regex` to extract text within quotes.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Capture any non-quotes that occur within double quotes.
  boost::regex re("\"([^\"]+)\"");

  // Input text
  std::string memoIN = "This is a \"Double\" Quote and this is \"another one\"";

  // Iterate through memoIN
  boost::sregex_iterator m1(memoIN.begin(), memoIN.end(), re);

  // Ending iterator (using the default constructor)
  boost::sregex_iterator m2;

  for (; m1 != m2; ++m1) {
    // Replace this with code to organize memoOUT
    std::cout << (*m1)[1].str() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Using a lexer library**

Depending on how sophisticated your needs are, you may find that you're better in the long run using a dedicated lexer and parser generator (like [ANTLR3 C](http://www.antlr3.org/api/C/)) than writing your own with Boost.Regex.

**Interfacing with UnicodeString**

There are several approaches to handling mismatches between C++Builder's `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString` and Standard C++'s `std::string` and `std::wstring`. One simple approach is to convert `UnicodeString` to `std::string` for internal text manipulation then convert it back to `UnicodeString` for the UI.  For example:

```
// Use AnsiString to convert from UTF-16 to a narrow character encoding
std::string memoIN_text = AnsiString(MemoIN->Text).c_str();

std::string memoOUT_text;
// Insert Boost.Regex manipulation here and assign the results to memoOUT_text

// Use implicit conversion from const char* to AnsiString/UnicodeString
MemoOUT->Text = memoOUT_text.c_str();
```

Converting from Unicode to ANSI may lose data, so you may want to use [SetMultiByteConversionCodePage](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SetMultiByteConversionCodePage) to tell C++Builder to use UTF-8 for AnsiString.  (Character encoding is complicated enough to be its own topic.)

Comment: first thanks for the quick reply, but for my case memoIN text type = UnicodeString and i don't know how to convert it to apply your code, and about the lexer generator i can't use it because it's a given work and we have to design our own Lexer.

Comment: and just to be clear on something i am using `c++ builder XE6` no `main` method no `return` no `cout`

Comment: @rep - I updated my answer to handle `UnicodeString`. I realize that `main` and `cout` aren't used in a C++Builder GUI app, but you can do C++Builder console apps, and regardless, it's a simple way to illustrate the concepts.

Comment: I don't what to say, THANKS This website rocks and you sir you're the man.
Many thanks will try what you said (y).

Comment: @rep: Note that this solution is not set up to handle strings with escape sequences correctly. String literal are usually designed to include escape sequence to specify non-printable characters or the string literal delimiter.

Comment: Changed the title to `[ANSWERED]` , Thanks to @JoshKelley

Comment: @rep - You're welcome. Stack Overflow works differently than other sites; marking an answer as accepted indicates that the question is answered, so there's no need to change the question title, and upvoting and marking an answer as accepted indicates thanks and is considered more appropriate than a "thank you" comment.